# Pegar dados de outra tabela em mysql e quantidade

Tags: mysql, sql

Estou com muitas dúvidas em relação ao MySQL quando tenho que utilizar o `INNER JOIN` para pegar dados de outras tabelas.

*Tenho 3 tabelas:*

**MEDIA**

id, user_id, title, description

**COMMENTS**

id, user_id, media_id, comment

**MEDIA_LIKES**

id, user_id, media_id

A tabela MEDIA é a principal, nela contem o `id do post` e `id do usuário`, depois tenho a tabela comments aonde tem os comentários postados em determinados posts e depois o `like` dado também nestes posts.

A minha grande dúvida é como através de uma ***Query*** no MySQL eu consiga pegar o os dados da tabela `MEDIA`, a quantidade de comentários e `likes` dados para determinado `media_id`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sua query vai ser assim:

```
SELECT
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM comments WHERE media_id='214') as comentarios, 
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM media_likes WHERE media_id='214') as likes,
  a.*
from media a where a.id='214';
```

isso se vc quiser puxar de apenas 1 id agora se quiser de todos basta tirar o where.

---OBS pos edit---
onde ta 214 vc poe a sua $var

**SS**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: amigo, tentei assim
<br><br>
"SELECT count(b.id) as likes, count(c.id) as comentarios, a.* from media a, media_likes b, comments c WHERE a.id=214;"
<br><br>
Mais só veio o titulo e o likes e comentarios ficaram zerados aparecendo zero e eu já conferi e existe likes para o media_id 214, oque poder ser?

Comment: foi mal eu tinha colado mas não foi tudo , ja aecertei a query

Comment: Jasar, deu certo agora mano, muito obrigado por sua ajuda deu certinho :D obrigado mesmo, nunca iria conseguir montar uma query assim >( valeu mesmo pela ajuda

Comment: cara, sinceramente, eu tbm cheguei num momento q eu não sabia montar as queries, o meu ponto de quebra foi quando comecei a entender como funciona , a logica em si. Tente desenhar a query que ajuda. vc desenha as tabelas e uma se encontra com a outra essa he a consulta básica q vc faz depois é so por o resto das condições necessárias para puxar a info q vc precisa.

Comment: vou tentar seguir essa logica, mais ainda não to conseguindo entender como funciona rs, uma última duvida que vi agora, não to conseguindo recuperar o resultado do numero de comentários, oque pode está acontecendo, minha query com sua ajuda ficou assim
"SELECT count(b.id) as likes, count(c.id) as comment, a.* from media a, media_likes b, comments c where a.id='214' and a.id=b.media_id and a.id=c.media_id;"

Comment: parece q ta certo, tem comentários com media_id 214?

Comment: tem 1, mais ta aparecendo 3 como o media_likes, ta repetindo, se eu colocar mais 1 no media_likes ele repete na chamada que eu faço do count para o comment

Comment: vc pode m dar uma copia deste db para eu testar ? dai eu monto a query e t passo

Comment: segue abaixo o arquivo para download http://www.filedropper.com/teste_4 agradeço a atenção. muito obrigado :D

Comment: resolvido ^^ ta editado ai em cima a query funcionando

Comment: Tu é sinistro mano! valeu mesmo, muito obrigado por sua ajuda, me salvou! valeu mesmo, muito obrigado :D

Comment: rsss q isso preciso he so posta por aqui. c eu nao tive pra ajuda outros irão. como vc tbm estou aprendendo. boa sorte ai

Comment: tmj leke, brigadão e valeu!

Answer (score 1):

Não sei bem, mas, acho que seria dessa forma:

```
SELECT media.id, 
       media.user_id, 
       media.title, 
       media.description, 
       count(comments.id) quantidade_comentarios, 
       count(media_likes.id) quantidade_likes
FROM media_likes
INNER JOIN comments.user_id=media_likes.user_id AND comments.media_id=media_likes.media_id
INNER JOIN media.id=comments.media_id AND media.user_id=comments.user_id
WHERE media.id=10;
GROUP BY media.id, media.user_id, media.title, media.description
```

aonde `WHERE media.id=10` no lugar do **10** o valor que deseja *filtrar*.

Comment: não deu certo amigo, ta dando erro :( obrigado por sua ajuda

Comment: qual é o erro, talvez seja algum letra, me informe o erro?

Comment: esse aqui: Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers erro '80040e14'

[MySQL][ODBC 5.3(a) Driver][mysqld-5.6.30-cll-lve]You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.user_id AND comments.media_id = media_likes.media_id INNER JOIN media.id = comm' at line 1

Comment: @Patrique as suas tabelas estão como você especificou na consulta, porque eu olhei na sua pergunta e reproduzi os campos igualzinhos, inclusive conferi, você poderia conferir se os campos corresponde? se por acaso quiser editar e colar uma imagem das três tabelas isso também pode ajudar a resolver seu problema. Vale lembrar que o erro é de sintaxe (como está escrito e isso pode esta errado na sua pergunta).